# `raise-frame` not adding frame to `(visible-frame-list)`

Tags: frames

I'm running Emacs 24.5.1 as a daemon on Fedora 24 with GNOME 3.20, and am encountering a strange behavior.

With two frames, `F1` (the initial frame) and `G1` (the created frame), if `G1` is iconified with `iconify-or-deiconify-frame`, then raised again with `(raise-frame (selected-frame))`, `G1` does not appear in `(visible-frame-list)`.

I think this is probably a GNOME problem, but I'm curious as to whether others have come across it.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: I know about `report-emacs-bug`; I'm wondering if this is actually an Emacs problem.

Comment: If there is no notation in the doc-string for `visible-frame-list` that says it works for all operating systems except Fedora 24 with GNOME 3.20, then it is a bug.  You might want to try the release candidate of Emacs 25 beforehand, just in case it has already been fixed.  This is not something that is properly resolvable on emacs.stackexchange.com.